# Way to take multiple input from same line separated by a space

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I need to store three names in three different variables but taking input from a single line separated by spaces between them. Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be able to use the bash shell's built in `read` command for that.

```
$ read -p "Please enter names: " name1 name2 name3
Please enter names: alice bob carol
$ echo $name1
alice
$ echo $name2
bob
$ echo $name3
carol
```

Comment: is the `-p` flag for that purpose?

Comment: @AbhishtaGatya the `-p` flag introduces the prompt string - see `help read`